# WP_Query order posts by category

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, theme-development, order

In a custom WP_Query I want to order posts by category. I mean that I want to show posts with `term_id=1291` first and then show other posts.
when I use two WP_Query , I cant use pagination.

"**edited**"

I tried this at first. I thought when I use `post__in`, `wp_query` ,keep posts order in `post__in`.

```
$c_cat=$_GET["c_cat"]
$query1 = new WP_Query(array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $c_cat,
        )
    )
));

$query1_ids=array();
foreach ($query1->posts as $p){
    array_push($query1_ids,$p->ID);
}

//new query, using post__in parameter
$finalQuery = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $query1_ids));
```

Comment: Does it have to be a single query? If not, you could just use `category__in` and `category__not_in`.

Comment: yes it has to be a single query? @kero

Comment: Can you paste the code that you already tried, it would be easier to help once we see your code

Comment: post edited @Buttered_Toast

Comment: `$query1` will contain posts from the category that you requested **only**, if you want the ids you can add a property `fields` with the value `ids` so like this `'fields' => 'ids'`